# A Stored Procedure for multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

### I want to write a stored procedure for my Tables that have a similar format

for example

```
tbl#Students(id int,name nvarchar(100))
tbl#Teachers(id int,name nvarchar(100))
```

This code is not correct but discuss my purpose

```
declare @b nvarchar(100)
set @b='TBL#Students'
declare @a nvarchar(100)
set @a= 'select * from '+@b
exec @a
//Error : Could not find stored procedure 'select * from TBL#Motamem'.
```

What is the correct code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
exec(@a);
```

If the parentheses are omitted, sql-server will consider @a as a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Add parenthesis after exec:

```
declare @b nvarchar(100) 
set @b='alerts' 
declare @a nvarchar(100) 
set @a= 'select * from '+@b 
exec (@a )
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the previous answers would be:

```
Exec sp_executesql @a
```